# How to create a 64 bit Unique Integer in Java

Tags: java, random, 64-bit, long-integer, uuid

I need to create a 64 bit unique integer in Java so that collision chances are low. The system is not distributed, so collisions between different computers are not a problem.

Is there any way, we can create a 64 bit integer in Java which is always Unique?

As of now I am using -

```
long number = System.nanoTime();
```

Is this the right way  to generate 64 bit Unique Integer in Java or is there anything else I can try?

**UPDATE:-**

How about doing this way? Will this be unique?

```
UUID number = UUID.randomUUID();
long uniqueNumber = number.timestamp();
```

Comment: sure. `i = 0`, then `i++` whenever you need a new one.

Comment: Here what are you meaning by collision chance?

Comment: @MarcB Or start at `Long.MIN_VALUE` to make it last even more ridiculously long.

Comment: Since `nanoTime()` will give you the time in nanoseconds, that seems to be pretty unique. Then you can just do `Integer unique64Integer = (int) number;`

Comment: Do you need random values?

Comment: @Ascalonian barring generics, never use `Integer`, plus `int`s are 32 bit...

Comment: @LocHa It doesn't matter to me whether it is random or not. It has to be unique that's all so that's why I started with `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html is your choice. It is thread-safe too.

Comment: @bcsb1001 - Good point! I guess I was just thinking about creating an Integer from a long. Thanks for the correction

Comment: I edited my answer in response to the update in the question.

Comment: Do you need uniqueness on one machine or across machines?

Comment: @Peter: The program I have will be run only on one machine, that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need the numbers to be unique in one process, robust between restarts, you can use a simple AtomicLong and a timer.

```
private static final AtomicLong TS = new AtomicLong();
public static long getUniqueTimestamp() {
    long micros = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        long value = TS.get();
        if (micros <= value)
            micros = value + 1;
        if (TS.compareAndSet(value, micros))
            return micros;
    }
}
```

This will give you a unique "timestamp" with a millisecond accuracy but can only handle 1000 ids per millisecond without getting ahead of the actual time.  This works fine on restart as the time will jump past previous values (again assuming you have less than one million per second on average)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In your example, what is micro? Is it `micros`, right.

Comment: @david micro-seconds.

Comment: ohkk got it. Looks like there is a type in your suggestion then. You are using `micro` and initialized `micros`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) in order to ensure uniqueness of the values you're storing. You can then check whether the insert was successful by checking what [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) returns. If the values have to be 'randomised' you can use your own algorithm, or check out [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

```
Long getUniqueNumber(HashSet uniqueNumberSet) {
    Long unique = generateUniqueNumber();
    if(!uniqueNumberSet.add(unique)) { // handle collision }
    return unique;
}
```

Comment: Really good solution! Hash tables are the way to go if you want to guarantee unique keys, OP.

Comment: If he needs it to be a long and not an int, then he is obviously going to be generating millions upon millions of them, so a hashset is completely out of the question for any purpose other than testing.

Comment: Also, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I think that your first point is a matter of choice for the OP. Either OP may increment a long, or the OP requires a fast (typically O(1), worst case O(logn)) method of checking uniqueness of values at insertion time.

Comment: Also, SecureRandom is a great source for secured random data to pump into a Long data structure generating unique values; I merely hinted as using an existing data structure to ensure uniqueness. It's an answer to the question.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I am sorry, I overlooked your suggestion about SecureRandom.  So, technically, your answer does in fact count as an answer to the question.  (Still not a good answer, in my humble opinion!)

Comment: You could use an AtomicLong instead of a HashSet if it only needs to be unique in a JVM.

Comment: We don't use Java 4 anymore - generics exist now. **Use them.**

Comment: @bcsb1001 technically we never used Java 4 ;)

Answer (score 1):

As `Marc B` said, the best approach is a simple `long` which is initialized with zero and incremented every time you need a new value.

If you need concurrency, or if performance is not an issue at all, then you can use `AtomicLong` as suggested by `Loc Ha`; however, if you really need it to be a long and not an int, then I suspect you are going to be generating lots of them, so you should probably avoid the extra overhead of `AtomicLong` unless you are sure you also need concurrency.

`System.nanoTime()` is not a good idea, as you have no guarantee that two consecutive calls to it will always yield different values.

EDIT (to cover update in question)

No, the timestamp part of the UUID is not guaranteed to be unique, for precisely the same reasons that System.nanoTime() is not guaranteed to be unique. If the timestamp of the UUID was unique, then there would be no need to have a UUID type, we would just always use that timestamp part.  Time is *always* a bad way to go about guaranteeing uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get unique ID, the appropriate way(although 128 bit):

```
UUID.randomUUID();
```

A bit less appropriate(collisions* are possible) with 64 bits:

```
UUID.getLeastSignificantBits();
UUID.getMostSignificantBits();
```

To really get unique ID(if they are critical to your operation):

1. Use centralised storage of all IDs
2. When you need an ID, let this centralised system handle it -> DB and auto incremented values are usually the easiest way

*collisions => 2 or more equal values

Comment: How about doing this way?   `UUID number = UUID.randomUUID();
  long uniqueNumber = number.timestamp();` Will this be unique?

Comment: If you want to use timestamp, then your original solution would be better. It all comes down to your use case. How frequently will you need this value and will you run multiple instances at the same time? Also, is this value something you critically rely on?

Comment: Subsequences of a UUID have no uniqueness guarantees by construction! (For example, if you use a version 1 UUID, your first 64-bits are just a timestamp and a constant). If you need a smaller-than-128-bit UID, you need to explore different algorithms (EID-64 from IEEE, Twitter's snowflake, etc.).