# How to create 64 bit number ID in a distributed environment

Tags: java, distributed

How to create a unique number of Java `long` type, in distributed environment ?
My requirement is :

1- 64 bit number

2- restart safe

3- Distributed environment

3- No collisions

Note that having a distributed environment without collisions rules out [simple approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370747/how-to-create-a-64-bit-unique-integer-in-java) using a counter or the current time.

Comment: @Mukit09 That's not for a distributed environment.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370747/how-to-create-a-64-bit-unique-integer-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a 64 bit Unique Integer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370747/how-to-create-a-64-bit-unique-integer-in-java)

Comment: Not similar . My requirement is unique in distributed system and  restart safe id

Comment: How many of these do you need per second - can you use a time for part of the number (which should also help the second requirement regarding restarts)?

Comment: I need at least 1000000 id per second , even more.

Comment: You will need some way to allocate separate spaces to machines -- assign each machine a small unique ID (< 1000 or so), or provide a way for them to communicate so they can negotiate the allocation of blocks of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Create an atomic id-generator-service(server) that holds state internally (on-disk) for restart safe
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxGAU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a distributed system, i.e. multiple executable instances are creating IDs and the id needs to be unique across all of the instances, you probably need to use something like a redis. Redis supports an automatic increment operation that would help you with that.

Comment: How i handle without redis ?

Comment: You will need something centralized, if you go down any other path, you will be building a lot more complex functionality. Another option is to partition the ID space and allocate it to all the instances, but that doesn't work with horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 0):

[Use AtomicLong and a Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370747/how-to-create-a-64-bit-unique-integer-in-java)

and than handle its value with Collections like Hashset for no collision.